# What kind of UDP protocol is this?

Tags: networking, udp

The software ensures that itself is alive by sending a keep alive message. When sending a specific message, it waits for the ACK to arrive, if not after timeout it will send the same message again (max for sending of this msg is 3 times). It looks like TCP but it is UDP.

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough information to identify a specific protocol - it could be any kind of reliable messaging protocol built over UDP. There are a number of reasons to build such a protocol - NAT evasion using [UDP hole punching](http://www.brynosaurus.com/pub/net/p2pnat/), [finer control over congestion control algorithm selection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro_Transport_Protocol), or simply avoiding TCP's message reordering, when the order in which messages are received is not important (this can help reduce latency).